# Uplink-limited vs. Downlink-limited

Tags: noise, link-budget

What is the definition of these terms? Would a system with signal to noise ratios of uplink 100dBHz and downlink 80dBHz be downlink-limited?

Comment: That's impossible to say. Systems are typically limited by more things than just their end-link bandwidths.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about amateur *radio* – a bandwidth of 100 dBHz (10 GHz) implies the channel is either optical or without the realm of amateur radio.

Comment: @MarcusMüller it's a C/N0 figure, not a bandwidth.

Comment: (they're dimensionally equivalent because noise density has units of power/Hz^-1, so power/noise density ends up with units of Hz, or dBHz)

Comment: @hobbs-KC2G makes sense, but makes it even harder to infer whether a system is limited through that – in the end, N0 doesn't matter; Eb/N0 does, and that's energy/powerdensity, and in my world that would be (power·time)/(power/freq)=1

Comment: Questions about the technology of radio (amateur or otherwise) are expressly on topic: https://ham.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: (I meant "power/Hz" or "power*Hz^-1" obviously. I over-reciprocated a little :)

Comment: This question sounds like an exam question. It needs more specific context before we can have a go at it though

Comment: @PhilFrost-W8II wholeheartedly agree, but as said, not the point that it's not about "amateur", the point is that it's not about *radio*, hence the emphasis in my vote.

Comment: @MarcusMüller It is about the *technology of radio*, as Phil correctly pointed out to you.